# Write HTML code to open PDF in browser

Tags: html, browser

I generate an html file from word document which has some links to pdf file. When I open it in some browsers, they download prompt comes up. What I need, is to open the pdf file in the same browser window.

I read that one solution is to include the following commands in header file:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; "filename.pdf"
```

However, I don't know which part of my pdf file I have to put them. Here is the header of my html code.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered)">
<base href=x>
<title>Welcome to SELSE-1, which we anticipate will be the first of a series of
annual workshops to bring together experts from both industry and academia to
discuss current and future trends in Soft Error Upset (SEU) rates and the state
of the art and possible</title>
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Wingdings;
    panose-1:5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"MS Mincho";
    panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"MS Mincho";
    panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Lucida Grande";}
@font-face
    {font-family:"\@MS Mincho";
    panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
h2
    {mso-style-link:"Heading 2 Char";
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:18.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
p.MsoCommentText, li.MsoCommentText, div.MsoCommentText
    {mso-style-link:"Comment Text Char";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader
    {mso-style-link:"Header Char";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter
    {mso-style-link:"Footer Char";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
p
    {margin-right:0in;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
p.MsoCommentSubject, li.MsoCommentSubject, div.MsoCommentSubject
    {mso-style-link:"Comment Subject Char";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}
p.MsoRMPane, li.MsoRMPane, div.MsoRMPane
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
span.maroon
    {mso-style-name:maroon;}
span.HeaderChar
    {mso-style-name:"Header Char";
    mso-style-link:Header;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
span.FooterChar
    {mso-style-name:"Footer Char";
    mso-style-link:Footer;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
span.Title1
    {mso-style-name:Title1;}
span.authors
    {mso-style-name:authors;}
span.CommentTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Comment Text Char";
    mso-style-link:"Comment Text";}
span.CommentSubjectChar
    {mso-style-name:"Comment Subject Char";
    mso-style-link:"Comment Subject";
    font-weight:bold;}
span.Heading2Char
    {mso-style-name:"Heading 2 Char";
    mso-style-link:"Heading 2";
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
    font-weight:bold;}
p.p1, li.p1, div.p1
    {mso-style-name:p1;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
p.Default, li.Default, div.Default
    {mso-style-name:Default;
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    text-autospace:none;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
    color:black;}
span.apple-converted-space
    {mso-style-name:apple-converted-space;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:10.0pt;}
 /* Page Definitions */
 @page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 89.85pt 64.9pt 89.85pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
 /* List Definitions */
 ol
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
ul
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
-->
</style>

</head>
```

Comment: Those headers *must* be sent from the web-server (they *cannot* be set from the HTML) to have any chance of working (and it will only work in some browsers with the appropriate extensions available) - this is because the Content Disposition is for the PDF resource and *not* the HTML, so meta-equiv (or any other altering of the HTML itself) is not applicable.

Comment: Furthermore, to display "in the same browser window" will require the use of an iframe (the PDF viewer takes over it all) or a plugin that displays PDFs (the embedded plugin is a DOM element) or a JavaScript PDF viewer (eg. full DOM building/access).

Comment: Is there any way to recommend the browser to open it in browser? For example, if I put <a href='Project.pdf'>Download</a> it will ask browser to download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force a browser to display a PDF, but you can tell it that it *can* if it is already set up to do so.

What you need to do is serve the file with the headers you mentioned. This tells the browser that the content it's loading is actually a PDF, and if it set up to open PDF's it will. Otherwise, a download is likely to be initiated.

More specifically, you need to attach the headers to the response given by the web-server when it fetches the file. The actual application can vary widely depending on your web-server and on how you're serving the file.

For example, if the file is served through a servlet, you can set the content-type inside the servlet (**java**):

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

If it is served directly (as in, you're just linking to the file with <a>) then you need to set this up on a server scale. For example, in **tomcat** you set this up in the **web.xml** file like so:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>pdf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

This sets the server in a way that any file served with a .pdf extension automatically receives the proper content-type.

Comment: How could I attach the headers to the web server response?

Comment: This varies widely depending on your web-server... For example, in Java it looks like `response.setContentType("application/pdf");`